# Not all Variables Bound Oracle REST Web API

Tags: c#, oracle, rest

I am getting Not all variables Bound.

Here is what My Code Looks Like.

```
public IEnumerable<VaultService> Get(string Branch_Desg)
{
    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);
    con.Open();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    //string sql = "select * from wemadummyvaulttable where branch_desg = " + Branch_Desg + "";
    string sql = "select BRANCH_ID ,BRANCH_NAME ,BRANCHID_NUMBER ,BRANCH_ACCOUNTNO ,BRANCH_DESG ,CURRENCY ,BRANCH_BALANCE from wemadummyvaulttable where Branch_Desg =" + ":Branch_Desg";

  OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(sql, con);
    da.Fill(dt);
    List<VaultService> vr = new List<Models.VaultService>(dt.Rows.Count);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow vaultrecord in dt.Rows)
        {
            vr.Add(new ReadVaultBal(vaultrecord));
        }
    }
    return vr;
}
```

For some Reason its not Working like its supposed to.

Screenshot Looks Like this :

[image]

Now My Updated Code Looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using WEMAVaultREST.Models;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types;
using System.Data;

namespace WEMAVaultREST.Controllers
{
    public class VaultServiceController : ApiController
    {
        string constr = "User ID=system; Password=admin1234; Data Source=SAM;";
        // GET api/<controller>
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/<controller>/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // GET api/<controller>/5
        /* public VaultService Get(string Branch_Desg)
         {
             OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);
             con.Open();
             DataTable dt = new DataTable();

             string sql = "select * from wemadummyvaulttable where branch_desg = '"+Branch_Desg+"'";
             OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(sql,con);
             da.Fill(dt);
             if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
             {
                 return new ReadVaultBal(dt.Rows[0]);
             }
             throw new Exception("Account not found");
         }*/

        public IEnumerable<VaultService> Get(string Branch_Desg)
        {
            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);
            con.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //string sql = "select * from wemadummyvaulttable where branch_desg = " + Branch_Desg + "";
            string sql = "select BRANCH_ID ,BRANCH_NAME ,BRANCHID_NUMBER ,BRANCH_ACCOUNTNO ,BRANCH_DESG ,CURRENCY ,BRANCH_BALANCE from wemadummyvaulttable where Branch_Desg =" + ":Branch_Desg";

            var command = new OracleCommand(sql, con);
            command.Parameters.Add("Branch_Desg", Branch_Desg);
            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
            da.Fill(dt);
            List<VaultService> vr = new List<Models.VaultService>(dt.Rows.Count);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow vaultrecord in dt.Rows)
                {
                    vr.Add(new ReadVaultBal(vaultrecord));
                }
            }
            return vr;
        }


        // POST api/<controller>
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/<controller>/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/<controller>/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Thats what i have for now. As you can see it Returns in Sqldeveloper.In the Code, it does not. I do not know what and where to Go from here.

If i run the REST api just like this :

```
http://localhost:7177/api/VaultService?Branch_Desg=Branch01
```

It returns this

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by this? I am getting Not all variables Bound

Comment: Its returning that as an Exception.Oracle Exception

Comment: Can you provide the complete exception

Comment: @viveknuna Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: 'ORA-01008: not all variables bound'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [REST Calls return empty List From Oracle Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62496047/rest-calls-return-empty-list-from-oracle-database)

Comment: it should be `string sql = "select BRANCH_ID ,BRANCH_NAME ,BRANCHID_NUMBER ,BRANCH_ACCOUNTNO ,BRANCH_DESG ,CURRENCY ,BRANCH_BALANCE from wemadummyvaulttable where Branch_Desg =" + Branch_Desg;
`

Comment: @viveknuna: no it absolutely should not.  For one thing, the questioner here is trying to do the right thing and use parameterised SQL, please don't drag them down the hole of writing code vulnerable to SQL injection.  For another, if you absolutely have to concatenate string values into a SQL string, you need to put quotes around the value.

Comment: @LukeWoodward OP has asked the same question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62496047/rest-calls-return-empty-list-from-oracle-database and he has mentioned that he will handle this later

Comment: @viveknuna: I know, I've seen that question.  Evidently they have given up with attempting to get their code working using your incorrect answer to that question.

Comment: @viveknuna, still complains invalid verifier

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the line

```
  OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(sql, con);
```

with

```
    var command = new OracleCommand(sql, con);
    command.Parameters.Add("Branch_Desg", branchDesg);
    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
```

It seems there isn't a way to add bind parameters directly to an `OracleDataAdapter`, so we have to create an `OracleCommand` from the SQL string first, add a value for the parameter `:Branch_Desg`, and then create the adapter from the command.

Finally, can I please recommend that all Oracle resources (connection, command and data-adapter) are disposed correctly, by creating them in `using` blocks, e.g.

```
using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr))
{
    // code using the database connection 'con'
}
```

Comment: Returns [] Empty set? Do you think stored procedure in Oracle Database can work??

Comment: If it's returning an empty set then (a) you're passing a value of `Branch_Desg` that isn't in the database, (b) you've inserted a suitable value into this table using a tool such as SQLPlus or SQL Developer but you haven't committed it, or (c) you're not connecting to the database you think you are.  If you run your query using a developer tool such as SQLPlus or SQL Developer, do you get the results you expect?

Comment: I can screenshot the DB and show you so you have a Look and Put me in right direction. Pls advise if i should do so

Comment: i use Sql developer, Once i run the code i get the result, if i send in Oracle, I see nothing

Comment: I'm not sure it's necessary to see a screenshot of the database.  It would be useful to know the type of the `BRANCH_DESG` column (e.g. `CHAR(...)` or `VARCHAR2(...)`), as that seems to be the one causing problems.

Comment: VARCHAR2 Thats what i used.

Comment: OK, so that rules out my theory that you have a `CHAR` column with trailing whitespace.  However, my first comment in this thread still stands.  Please verify (a) the value that gets passed to your method above is genuinely what you expect, (b) you have committed any transaction in which you inserted data in SQL Developer, and (c) please double-check you are connecting to the same database in SQL Developer and your C# code.  I'm not sure how else I can help: I got your code with my modifications fetching data from a database on my machine so in theory your code should work too.

Comment: Yes. its suppose to check the DB for values and return which values has branch Designation as Branch01, i have inserted values inside the DB and it has values. Pls see updated Code and screenshots

Comment: I have Updated with screens for your Viewing

Comment: In the SQL Developer screenshot, you are showing the `branch_desg` with value `Head Office`, but in the Postman screenshot you are setting `branch_desg` to `Branch01`.  What happens if you run the query in SQL Developer using `Branch01`, or the Postman query using `Head Office`?

Comment: Once i set the Branch_Desg to Branch01 or Headoffice it works fine in SQL developer. Like i said before , but once i send it to C# so i can read from Postman, it returns Null.

Comment: I really don't know how I can help any more.  I've created a new REST API project using the code in your controller method and it returned data as I would expect it to.  The code should work, it's really not clear why it doesn't for you.

Comment: is it possible , i upload my code so you can check there, Pls. So as to know where i am having my Errors